# How can I fix java.sql.SQLException: Value 14:50 cannot be converted to INTEGER error?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I want to list my data on a grid and I used hibernate for it on Java. But my code doesn't work and I get error. When I run my SQL script it works. I think there is an error on my code and there isn't an error on my SQL script. Code blocks and error screenshot is below. How can I fix it ?

DaoImp.java:

```
@Override public DealResponse radyolojiSorgulamaListesiAlt(List<BaseFilter> prmFilter, Integer start, Integer limit) {
        //sysFunc.writeDealLog_Start(new DealLog(_projeEnum.LogLevel.StartMethod, "tr.com.metasoft.deal.dao.sbs", "SbsIstemFisHastaDaoImpl", "istemHastaSiraListesi"));
        DealResponse response = new DealResponse();
        try {

            List<PatolojiSorusturmaUI> liste =new ArrayList<>();
            List<PatolojiSorusturmaUI> listeCount = new ArrayList<>();

            StringBuilder sqlAna = new StringBuilder();
            sqlAna.append(
                    "select dbo.IntegerIntoTime(sif.ISTEM_FS_SAAT)   as hstGelisSaati,\n" +
                            "hrk.ISTEM_DURUM as istemDurum,\n" +
                            "ACCESSION_NUMBER as accessionNumber,\n" +
                            "srck.RC_CIHAZ AS rcCihaz,srck.RC_CIHAZ_SEVK as rcSevkDurum,\n" +
                            "sd.DOKTOR_AD + ' '  + sd.DOKTOR_SOYAD  as cekimYapan,\n" +
                            "sifh.HASTA_GELIS_TRH as hstGelisTrh,\n" +
                            "dbo.IntegerIntoTime(sif.ISTEM_FS_SAAT) as hstGelisSaat,\n" +
                            "SBS_SAGLIK_RAPOR_ID as sbsSaglikRaporId,\n" +
                            "hrk.ISTSH_TRH  as sevkistemTrh,\n" +
                            "hrk.KABUL_TRH   as sevkkabulTrh,\n" +
                            "dbo.IntegerIntoTime(hrk.ISTSH_ISLEM_SAAT)  as sevkistemSaat,\n" +
                            "dbo.IntegerIntoTime(hrk.KABUL_SAAT )  as sevkkabulSaat,\n" +
                            "hrk.SEVK_ID as sevkId,NULL as teknisyen,\n" +
                            "hzm.HIZMET_SUT_KODU as Butce_Kodu,\n" +
                            "hzm.HIZMET_SUT_TANIMI as Butce_Tanimi,\n" +
                            "hrk.ISTSH_ID AS istem_Id\n"+

                            "from SBS_ISTEM_FIS  as sif  with(nolock)\n" +
                            "inner join SBS_ISTEM_FIS_HASTA as sifh with(nolock) on sif.ISTEM_FS_ID=sifh.SBS_ISTEM_FIS_ID and isnull(sif.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "inner join SBS_ISTEM_HAREKET as hrk with(nolock) on sif.ISTEM_FS_ID=hrk.ISTEM_FIS_ID and isnull(hrk.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "inner join SBS_ISTEM_FIS as siff        with(nolock) on siff.ISTEM_FS_ID=hrk.ISTEM_FIS_ID and (isnull(siff.PSF_ID,0)=0)\n" +
                            "inner join STOK_KART_HIZMET as hzm with(nolock) on hrk.ISTSH_STOKKART_ID = hzm.STOK_ID and (isnull(hzm.PSF_ID,0)=0)\n" +
                            "left join SBS_DOKTOR as sd with(nolock) on SD.KIMLIK_ID = HRK.UYGULAYACAK_HEKIM_KIMLIK_ID and (isnull(hzm.PSF_ID,0)=0)\n" +
                            "left join TUR_DETAY AS TD WITH(NOLOCK) ON TD.TUR_DETAY_ID=SD.CALISMA_TURU AND ISNULL(TD.PSF_ID,0)=0 AND (TD.TUR_DEGER_KOD='DISHEKIMI' or TD.TUR_DEGER_KOD='HEKIM')\n" +
                            "inner join SBS_HASTA  as hst with(nolock) on hst.HASTA_KIMLIK_ID=sifh.HASTA_KIMLIK_ID and isnull(hst.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "inner join  KIMLIK as k  with(nolock) on   k.KIMLIK_ID =sifh.HASTA_KIMLIK_ID  and  isnull(k.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "left join TUR_DETAY as tdc  with(nolock) on k.CINSIYET_TUR_ID = tdc.TUR_DETAY_ID  and  isnull(tdc.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "left join SBS_GIZLI_HASTA as gh ON gh.TC_KIMLIK_NO = sifh.KIMLIK_TC_NO and (GETDATE() BETWEEN gh.MAHKEME_TARIHI AND hst.GIZLILIK_BITIS_TARIH) and ISNULL(gh.PSF_ID,0) = 0\n" +
                            "left join BIRIM as b  with(nolock)  on b.BIRIM_ID = sifh.HASTA_SERVIS_ID and isnull(b.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "left join SBS_KLINIK as klinik  with(nolock) on b.BIRIM_ID = klinik.BIRIM_ID and isnull(klinik.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "left join SBS_KLINIK_UST as ust  with(nolock) on klinik.KLINIK_UST_ID = ust.KLINIK_UST_ID and (ISNULL(ust.PSF_ID,0)=0)\n" +
                            "left join TUR_DETAY as klinikTur  with(nolock) on klinik.KLINIK_TUR_ID = klinikTur.TUR_DETAY_ID and isnull(klinikTur.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "left join CARI_KURUM_TUR as ck  with(nolock) on  sifh.HASTA_KURUM_TUR_ID  = ck.KURUM_TUR_ID and isnull(ck.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "left join CARI_KART as cari  with(nolock) on sifh.HASTA_KURUM_ID = cari.CARI_KART_ID and isnull(cari.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "left join SBS_SIRA_TUR as siraTur  with(nolock)on hst.SIRA_TUR_ID = siraTur.SBS_SIRA_TUR_ID and isnull(siraTur.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "left join BIRIM as br on br.BIRIM_ID =sif.ISTEM_FS_ISTEM_YAPAN_BIRIM_ID\n" +
                            "left join BIRIM as ustBirim on ustBirim.BIRIM_ID =br.UST_BIRIM_ID\n" +
                            "left join KAYIT_DURUM as tdKayitDurum with(nolock) on tdKayitDurum.KAYIT_DURUM_ID=hrk.ISTSH_KAYIT_DURUM_ID   and isnull(tdKayitDurum.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "left join SBS_RONTGEN_CIHAZ as srck with(nolock) on srck.SBS_RONTGEN_CIHAZ_ID=hrk.RONTGEN_CIHAZ_ID  and isnull(srck.PSF_ID,0)=0\n" +
                            "left join BIRIM as rontgenBirim on  srck.RC_CIHAZ_SRVNO= rontgenBirim.BIRIM_ID\n" +
                            "left join BIRIM rontgenUstBirim on rontgenBirim.UST_BIRIM_ID =rontgenUstBirim.BIRIM_ID and rontgenUstBirim.BIRIM_ID =ustBirim.BIRIM_ID\n" +
                            "where (isnull(hrk.PSF_ID,0)=0)\n" +
                            "and (isnull(sifh.PSF_ID,0)=0)\n" +
                            "and  hzm.HIZMET_TUR  &4 =4\n");

            if (sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("baslangicTrh", prmFilter).fieldValue != null && sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("baslangicTrh", prmFilter).fieldValue != "") {
                sqlAna.append( " and sifh.HASTA_GELIS_TRH >= '"+(sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("baslangicTrh", prmFilter).fieldValue.toString()) + "'" + " \n");
            }
            if (sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("bitisTrh", prmFilter).fieldValue != null && sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("bitisTrh", prmFilter).fieldValue != "") {
                sqlAna.append( " and sifh.HASTA_GELIS_TRH <= '"+(sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("bitisTrh", prmFilter).fieldValue.toString()) + "'" + " \n");
            }
            if (sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("hastaTcKimlikNo", prmFilter).fieldValue != null && sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("hastaTcKimlikNo", prmFilter).fieldValue != "") {
                sqlAna.append( " and sifh.KIMLIK_TC_NO = '"+(sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("hastaTcKimlikNo", prmFilter).fieldValue.toString()) + "'" + " \n");
            }
            if (sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("birimAd", prmFilter).fieldValue != null && sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("birimAd", prmFilter).fieldValue != "") {
                sqlAna.append( " and sifh.HASTA_SERVIS_AD = '"+(sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("birimAd", prmFilter).fieldValue.toString()) + "'" + " \n");
            }
            if (sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("hekimAdSoyad", prmFilter).fieldValue != null && sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("hekimAdSoyad", prmFilter).fieldValue != "") {
                sqlAna.append( " and sifh.HEKIM_AD_SOYAD = '"+(sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("hekimAdSoyad", prmFilter).fieldValue.toString()) + "'" + " \n");
            }
            if (sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("hastaKodu", prmFilter).fieldValue != null && sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("hastaKodu", prmFilter).fieldValue != "") {
                sqlAna.append( " and hst.HASTA_KODU = '"+(sysFunc.getFilterInBaseFilterList("hastaKodu", prmFilter).fieldValue.toString()) + "'" + " \n");
            }
            sqlAna.append("group by sifh.HASTA_KIMLIK_ID," + " \n" );
            sqlAna.append("sifh.HASTA_GELIS_ID," + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("sifh.HST_GELIS_KOD," + " \n" );
            sqlAna.append("sifh.HASTA_AD_SOYAD,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("hst.HASTA_KODU,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("(sd.DOKTOR_AD +' ' + sd.DOKTOR_SOYAD),"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("(b.BIRIM_AD),"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("sifh.KIMLIK_TC_NO,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("ck.KURUM_TUR_TANIM,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("sifh.HASTA_KURUM_TUR_ID,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("dbo.IntegerIntoTime(sif.ISTEM_FS_SAAT),"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("cari.CARI_KART_ADI,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("cari.CARI_KART_ADI,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("klinikTur.TUR_DEGER_KOD,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("hst.SIRA_TUR_ID,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("siraTur.Ad,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("gh.HASTA_RUMUZ,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("hst.GIZLILIK_BITIS_TARIH,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("b.BIRIM_ID,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("sd.KIMLIK_ID,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("convert(date ,sif.ISTEM_FS_TRH ,102),"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("hrk.ISTEM_DURUM,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("cast(convert(date,sifh.KIMLIK_DOGUM_TRH,102) as nvarchar), "  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("ACCESSION_NUMBER,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("srck.RC_CIHAZ,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("srck.RC_CIHAZ_SEVK,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("sd.DOKTOR_AD + ' '  + sd.DOKTOR_SOYAD,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("sifh.HASTA_GELIS_TRH,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("sif.ISTEM_FS_SAAT,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("SBS_SAGLIK_RAPOR_ID,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("hrk.ISTSH_TRH,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("hrk.KABUL_TRH,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("dbo.IntegerIntoTime(hrk.ISTSH_ISLEM_SAAT),"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("dbo.IntegerIntoTime(hrk.KABUL_SAAT ),"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("hrk.SEVK_ID,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("hzm.HIZMET_SUT_KODU,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("hzm.HIZMET_SUT_TANIMI,"  + " \n");
            sqlAna.append("hrk.ISTSH_ID");

            org.hibernate.Query queryListCount = hibernate().createSQLQuery(sqlAna.toString()).addScalar("hstGelisSaati",StringType.INSTANCE)
                    .addScalar("istemDurum",IntegerType.INSTANCE).addScalar("accessionNumber", StringType.INSTANCE).addScalar("rcCihaz",StringType.INSTANCE)
                    .addScalar("rcSevkDurum",IntegerType.INSTANCE).addScalar("cekimYapan",StringType.INSTANCE).addScalar("hstGelisTrh", DateType.INSTANCE)
                    .addScalar("hstGelisSaat",IntegerType.INSTANCE).addScalar("sbsSaglikRaporId",IntegerType.INSTANCE).addScalar("sevkistemTrh",DateType.INSTANCE)
                    .addScalar("sevkkabulTrh",DateType.INSTANCE).addScalar("sevkistemSaat",IntegerType.INSTANCE).addScalar("sevkkabulSaat",IntegerType.INSTANCE)
                    .addScalar("teknisyen",StringType.INSTANCE).addScalar("Butce_Kodu",IntegerType.INSTANCE).addScalar("Butce_Tanimi",StringType.INSTANCE)
                    .addScalar("istem_Id",IntegerType.INSTANCE);

            liste = queryListCount.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SbsKlinikSevkUI.class)).list();
            //sih.ACIL_ONCELIK_TURU ,sih.ISTSH_ISLEM_SAAT,SHRU.HST_GELIS_SAAT, sih.ACCESSION_NUMBER,sih.KABUL_TRH
            response.setData(liste);
            response.setTotal(liste.size());
            response.setSuccessful(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setSuccessful(false);
            response.setMessageCode("SISTEM.ERROR.0001");
        }
        return response;
```

UIModel.java:

```
private String hstGelisSaati;

private Integer istemDurum;

private String accessionNumber;

private String rcCihaz;

private Integer rcSevkDurum;

private String cekimYapan;

private Date hstGelisTrh;

private Integer hstGelisSaat;

private Integer sbsSaglikRaporId;

private Date sevkistemTrh;

private Date sevkkabulTrh;

private Integer sevkistemSaat;

private Integer sevkkabulSaat;

private Integer Butce_Kodu;

private String Butce_Tanimi;

private Integer istem_Id;


public String getHstGelisSaati() {
        return hstGelisSaati;
    }

    public void setHstGelisSaati(String hstGelisSaati) {
        this.hstGelisSaati = hstGelisSaati;
    }

 public Integer getIstemDurum() {
        return istemDurum;
    }

    public void setIstemDurum(Integer istemDurum) {
        this.istemDurum = istemDurum;
    }

    public String getAccessionNumber() {
        return accessionNumber;
    }

    public void setAccessionNumber(String accessionNumber) {
        this.accessionNumber = accessionNumber;
    }

    public Integer getRcSevkDurum() {
        return rcSevkDurum;
    }

    public void setRcSevkDurum(Integer rcSevkDurum) {
        this.rcSevkDurum = rcSevkDurum;
    }

    public String getCekimYapan() { 
        return cekimYapan; }

    public void setCekimYapan(String cekimYapan) { 
        this.cekimYapan = cekimYapan; }

    public Date getHstGelisTrh() {
        return hstGelisTrh;
    }

    public void setHstGelisTrh(Date hstGelisTrh) {
        this.hstGelisTrh = hstGelisTrh;
    }
   
    public Integer getHstGelisSaat() {
        return hstGelisSaat;
    }

    public void setHstGelisSaat(Integer hstGelisSaat) {
        this.hstGelisSaat = hstGelisSaat;
    }

    public Integer getSbsSaglikRaporId() {
        return sbsSaglikRaporId;
    }

    public void setSbsSaglikRaporId(Integer sbsSaglikRaporId) {
        this.sbsSaglikRaporId = sbsSaglikRaporId;
    }

    public Date getsevkistemTrh() {
        return sevkistemTrh;
    }

    public void setsevkistemTrh(Date sevkistemTrh) {
        this.sevkistemTrh = sevkistemTrh;
    }

    public Date getsevkkabulTrh() {
        return sevkkabulTrh;
    }

    public void setsevkkabulTrh(Date sevkkabulTrh) {
        this.sevkkabulTrh = sevkkabulTrh;
    }

    public Integer getsevkistemSaat() {
        return sevkistemSaat;
    }

    public void setsevkistemSaat(Integer sevkistemSaat) {
        this.sevkistemSaat = sevkistemSaat;
    }

    public Integer getsevkkabulSaat() {
        return sevkkabulSaat;
    }

    public void setsevkkabulSaat(Integer sevkkabulSaat) {
        this.sevkkabulSaat = sevkkabulSaat;
    }

    public Integer getButce_Kodu() {
        return Butce_Kodu;
    }

    public void setButce_Kodu(Integer Butce_Kodu) {
        this.Butce_Kodu = Butce_Kodu;
    }

    public String getButce_Tanimi() {
        return Butce_Tanimi;
    }

    public void setButce_Tanimi(String Butce_Tanimi) {
        this.Butce_Tanimi = Butce_Tanimi;
    }

    public Integer getIstem_Id() {
        return istem_Id;
    }

    public void setistem_Id(Integer istem_Id) {
        this.istem_Id = istem_Id;
    }
```

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FphM.png)

Comment: You have a time value (perhaps) as string, that you either want to use as parameter with the wrong type or convert to result with the wrong data type

Comment: I couldn't find it. Which parameter do you say? @XtremeBaumer

Comment: How would I know? You havent provided the whole stack trace nor any example data

Comment: I solved the problem but there is another problem. I used integer to time function for convert integer time column what in database and I delete the function for hibernate. When I delete the function problem was fixed. So how can I convert the column integer to time ?